# How to disable Reader View in Firefox using webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

Whenever I run my test in firefox, 'Reader View' message box pops up in the address bar. This pop up hides the element from view, so Webdriver is throwing "ElementnotvisibleException. This pop up is displayed for the pages in languages other than English. 
I disabled the reader view option. This does not help me much.Any thoughts on how to overcome this issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain: "This does not help me much." What did you try? What happened? What exactly would you like to see happen?

Comment: Well @SiKing, try guessing... "I disabled", Where? on the opened (with a new profile) firefox. "This doesn't help" Why? changes are not saved, or even if saved, a new launch of firefox will create a new (unconfigured) profile. Problem? Somewhat called userxxxxxxxx, (ibcac, interface between chair and computer)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

> ```
> @Before
> public void setUp() throws Exception {
>     FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
>     firefoxProfile.setPreference("reader.parse-on-load.enabled",false);
>     driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
>     baseUrl = "http://google.com";
>     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
> }
> ```

should do it.

Comment: The important thing here (as user didn't say language to use) is to create a new profile, then set it's preference "reader.parse-on-load.enabled" to "false".

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same issue. The initial load of a Firefox browser showed the Reader View alert and the test couldn't see the page elements behind the alert. Although I turned off the Reader View on the Firefox about:config page, the raw FF browser that my test starts does not regard that setting.

My solution was simply to program a reload of the page. The subsequent page load doesn't show the Reader View alert and things work as I intended.

A bonus to this simple solution is that it will work for whomever runs the test - you won't need to require a Firefox admin tweak for all who run the test.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple thing you can tackle this kind of inconvenience. Just use refresh code for this script.

For Example: 

`driver.navigate().refresh();`

Answer (score -2):

1. Navigate to about: config
2. To remove Reader view, change reader.parse-on-load.enabled preference value to ‘false‘.

Or just downgrade your Firefox. Mozilla enabled Reader view feature in Firefox 38.0.5

Comment: Selenium starts with a blank new profile each time it start up Firefox. This setting will get reset to factory defaults.

Comment: I tried to remove Reader View, but as Siking said firefox opens with default when I run the script

Comment: U can: use a real and current profile from your profiles folder.
U can: save profile back then load it many times, which includes changes, settings and of course, extensions if you need them (well, u can install extensions on the fly... of course).