# How to pass custom Firefox settings to WebDriver.dart

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dart

I run into [How to disable Reader View in Firefox using webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764805) but the solution provided in the answer can't be used as is in Dart with [WebDriver.dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdriver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a Firefox profile or use an existing one.
- Create a `user.js` file within the profile directory with the content shown below.
- Create a zip archive file containing all files from the profile directory (the zip archive file must not have a root directory, the files and directories of the used profile must be top-level files and directories in the zip archive).
- Pass the zip archive file to the `desired` parameter.

For me it also worked when I just added the `prefs.js` and `user.js` files to the zip archive file.

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
...
var firefoxProfile = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(
    new io.File('/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/webdriver_profile.zip').readAsBytesSync());
var driver = createDriver(uri: uri, 
    desired: {'browserName': Browser.firefox, 'firefox_profile': firefoxProfile});
```

**user.js**

```
// turn off reader view message
user_pref("reader.parse-on-load.enabled", false);
```